# Grothendieck dessins d'enfants - current surveys or text you can recommend?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, graph-theory, gn.general-topology, textbook-recommendation

I was recommended this forum to be the leading site for algebraic geometry, so I would like to ask you a question about Grothendieck dessins d´enfants. My background is in maps on surfaces (graph embeddings), and I got fascinated about their application to dessins d´enfants.

As an example, I found it completely stunning when I saw the first time that the least genus embedding of $K_{n,n,n}$ (the complete tripartite graph with $3n$ vertices), when viewed as a dessin d'enfants, specifies the Fermat curve. (cf. Jones & Singermann "Maps, Hypermaps, and Triangle Groups" in:  Schneps (ed.): The Grothendieck Theory of Dessins d’Enfants. London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series 200, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge 1994)

> So I would like to look for more areas of potential application of graph embeddings to dessins d'enfants, but don't have a good overview yet over recent developments in this field.

> Would you be able to recommend a recent survey of dessins d'enfants, or a good recent text to me?

I am not sure whether I am using the right tags for this, please feel free to adjust!

Comment: I don't know to what extent it fits your criteria, but it's probably worth having a look at the book by Ernesto Girondo and Gabino González-Diez, ‘Introduction to Compact Riemann Surfaces and Dessins d'Enfants’ (LMS Student Texts **79** (2012)).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Merci beaucoup! Very grateful for your suggestion! As I am new to this forum, I am not sure how to give you upvote credit for your help? Would be happy to express my thanks

Comment: Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" sections 4.6-4.9 are a great background to the subject matter, but they don't go into much detail about the dessins themselves.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal Thank you very much for your recommendation! Very interested in that

Comment: See Jones & Wolfart, "Dessins d'Enfants on Riemann Surfaces" (Springer, 2016).

Comment: @TomHarris Thank you for this suggestion! I will definitely take a look.